# Filtering a multiindex dataframe based on column values dropping all rows inside level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to filter a DataFrame based on one or more values. Here is an example CSV:

```
AlignmentId,TranscriptId,classifier,value
ENSMUST00000025010-1,ENSMUST00000025010,AlnCoverage,0.99612
ENSMUST00000025010-1,ENSMUST00000025010,AlnIdentity,0.93553
ENSMUST00000025010-1,ENSMUST00000025010,Badness,0.06749
ENSMUST00000025014-1,ENSMUST00000025014,AlnCoverage,1.0
ENSMUST00000025014-1,ENSMUST00000025014,AlnIdentity,0.96382
ENSMUST00000025014-1,ENSMUST00000025014,Badness,0.03618
```

And when loaded:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', index_col=['AlignmentId', 'TranscriptId'])
>>> df
                                          classifier    value
AlignmentId          TranscriptId
ENSMUST00000025010-1 ENSMUST00000025010  AlnCoverage  0.99612
                     ENSMUST00000025010  AlnIdentity  0.93553
                     ENSMUST00000025010      Badness  0.06749
ENSMUST00000025014-1 ENSMUST00000025014  AlnCoverage  1.00000
                     ENSMUST00000025014  AlnIdentity  0.96382
                     ENSMUST00000025014      Badness  0.03618
```

I want to drop every `AlignmentId` group that fail a series of `classifiers`. For this example, lets say that I want to drop `ENSMUST00000025010` because `AlnCoverage < 1.0`. Thus, I want to end up with this dataframe:

```
ENSMUST00000025014-1 ENSMUST00000025014  AlnCoverage  1.00000
                     ENSMUST00000025014  AlnIdentity  0.96382
                     ENSMUST00000025014      Badness  0.03618
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [169]: df = df.drop(df[(df.classifier=='AlnCoverage') & (df.value < 1)].index)

In [170]: df
Out[170]:
                                          classifier    value
AlignmentId          TranscriptId
ENSMUST00000025014-1 ENSMUST00000025014  AlnCoverage  1.00000
                     ENSMUST00000025014  AlnIdentity  0.96382
                     ENSMUST00000025014      Badness  0.03618
```